# Is there any memory cell that can store more than one bit?

Tags: memory, computer-architecture, vlsi, non-volatile-memory

SRAM, DRAM, Flash, EPROM - all of the memory cells contain one bit of data each. Is there any memory cell that can store more than one bit, e.g. 2 bits/4bits?

Comment: I don't know why you couldn't use google to find [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~phoenix/nsc1/presentation/Dubrova.pdf). It sure came up very easy for me as the first link. Read it through.

Comment: Short answer, yes

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  When you get down to the level of a memory cell, the circuitry is pretty analog.  So you can store multiple voltage levels in the cell, and interpret those multiple levels as encoding more than one bit.

There are parts in production that use this.

Google "multi-level memory".

Comment: I don't think this is true, in general, and is at best misleading. SRAM memory cells use positive feedback so they can reliably store 1 bit. DRAM cells deal with significant charge leakage and have to be refreshed often just to hold one 1 bit per cell. Mask programmed ROM is inherently one bit per cell. Only Flash memory offers a practical way to store multiple bits per cell.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson consider that most of the memory cells that exist in the world *are* multi-level flash cells.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Perhaps, but most of the **types** of memory cells are not multi-level cells, and this answer says that "a memory cell", without qualification, can store multiple levels. That is simply not true.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you’ll have a really hard time to find a NAND flash device that does ***not*** store more than one bit per cell nowadays. This is one of the reasons the price of memory cards and SSDs (in terms of $/GB) has dropped so dramatically over the years.

Comment: And if you want one that only stores one, you pay for it.  So much that there's an intermediate solution where they put multiple copies of the same bit in the multi-bit cell!

Answer (score 1):

Of the semiconductor memories on the market, only some Flash EPROM technologies store more than 1 data bit per memory cell.

As an example, the Cypress Mirrorbit technology stores two data bit in a single Flash memory element, utilising four stored voltages to do so. You'll find details of those parts on the internet.

Comment: [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell) claims that Samsung has 8-level memory on the market, with three bits/cell.  I didn't try chasing that down to the level of data sheets or marketing from Samsung, however.

Comment: [Micron has QLC (16-level!!) flash memory.](https://www.micron.com/products/advanced-solutions/qlc-nand)